# What would the function $f$ look like, that returns $1$ if an integer $x = 0$ and an integer $y \neq 0$, and returns $0$ otherwise?

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

What would the function $f$ look like, that returns $1$ if an integer $x = 0$ and an integer $y \neq 0$, and returns $0$ otherwise?

Examples:

1. $ x = 0\; ,\; y = 3 \quad then \quad f_{(x, y)} = 1 $
2. $ x = 6\; ,\; y = 2 \quad then \quad f_{(x, y)} = 0 $
3. $ x = 0\; ,\; y = 0 \quad then \quad f_{(x, y)} = 0 $

Comment: If $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=1$, for $x\neq0$, then you could make $$f(x,y)=g(x)'\wedge g(y).$$

Comment: Why not just use [definition by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise)?

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
1&&\text{if }x=0\text{ and }y\ne0\\
0&&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling, and searching other questions here, I came up with this:

\begin{equation}
f_{(x, y)} = \lceil \frac{y}{\left( k \cdot x + 1 \right) \cdot \left( y + 1 \right)} \rceil \quad when \;\; k\to\infty
\end{equation}